# How highlight specific row values in a table based on a condition

Tags: r, formattable

I have a dataframe

```
structure(list(date = c("4/12/2021", "4/13/2021", "4/14/2021", 
"4/15/2021", "4/16/2021", "4/17/2021", "4/18/2021", "Change", 
"Change (%)"), price1= c(44.42, 43.77, 
43.77, 44.35, 44.4, NA, NA, 0.609999999999999, 1.40126803271157
), price2= c(40.68, 41.73, 45.22, 47.68, 47.35, 44.33, 43.34, 
14.6685714285714, 49.4485913797255)), row.names = c("8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "1", "15"), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to use `formattable` package and `formattable()` function.
It is necessary to highlight cells in rows Change and Change % with green if positive value and red if negative value. I found a similar function [here](https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/prettytables), however it is working only with columns ( `` `2015`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0) `` part)

Could you help with finding solution how to do it for rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `area` function. You can specify the rowindex for coloring in the `row` argument. If you are not interested in coloring the whole row (just rows of certain columns), you can define these columns in the `col` argument.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("4/12/2021", "4/13/2021", "4/14/2021", 
                        "4/15/2021", "4/16/2021", "4/17/2021", "4/18/2021", "Change", 
                        "Change (%)"), price1= c(44.42, 43.77, 
                                                 43.77, 44.35, 44.4, NA, NA, 0.609999999999999, 1.40126803271157
                        ), price2= c(40.68, 41.73, 45.22, 47.68, 47.35, 44.33, 43.34, 
                                     14.6685714285714, 49.4485913797255)), row.names = c("8", "9", 
                                                                                         "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "1", "15"), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code**

```
library(formattable)

# define row indices
row_change <- which(df$date == "Change")
row_change_percent <- which(df$date == "Change (%)")

# define coloring
red_green_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                                 style = x ~ style(
                                  display = "block",
                                `background-color` = ifelse(x < 0, "red", 
                                                ifelse(x > 0, "lightgreen", "white"))))

# set formattable and define coloring for rows 8 and 9 for every column but not the first
formattable(df,
            list(area(row = row_change:row_change_percent,
                      col = -1) ~ red_green_formatter))
```

[image]